# Changing decimal default precision entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I m working on a MVC 4 architecture .net project . The decimal parameter's default precision is (18,2). i did some migration changes and changed it to (18,6). so now the database stores 6 digits scale range after the decimal point .but the problem is that it is not storing the value set problematically. It picks only 2 digits and then rest it appends 0000 till six.

For example: if the user sends the 45.233222 the value stored in the database is 45.230000. 
manual entry into database works perfectly fine. 
im newbie working on this stuff ...so please suggest how to change the default precision of decimal parameter so that it in database it stores with six digit precision.

The migration change I've done.

```
public override void Up()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.TItems", "SubTotal", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 6));
            AlterColumn("dbo.TItems", "UnitPrice", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 6));
        }

public override void Down()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.TItems", "SubTotal", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2));
            AlterColumn("dbo.TItems", "UnitPrice", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2));
        }
```

Comment: How do you receive that values? Your problem seems reside on reading them.

Comment: those values are received via http post . And by putting breakpoints i can see the same 6 digit value in the post api response but when i save it in the database using db.savechanges the value stored has last 4 digits replaced with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I always assumed decimal (in entity framework migrations) is used for money. So precision is set at the model, not at the migration level. Use double for database, or float if you need to, then just cast as needed.